# How can I get the suggested values from an input datalist using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, autosuggest, optionmenu, html-datalist

I'm using a plain text input plus datalist to suggest values as the user interacts with the input. I'd like to know if there's a way to get the suggested items shown.

E.g.

```js
    document.getElementById('myBrowser').addEventListener('input', function() {
      console.log(this.list.suggested); // logs out the suggested values 
    });
```

```html
    <label for="myBrowser">Choose a browser from this list:</label>
    <input list="browsers" id="myBrowser" name="myBrowser" />
    <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Chrome"></option>
      <option value="Firefox"></option>
      <option value="Opera"></option>
      <option value="Safari"></option>
      <option value="Microsoft Edge"></option>
    </datalist>
```

So if I type 'Fire' the suggestion values should just be ['Firefox']

Comment: I'm trying the exact HTML code you shared, with no JS, and it's doing what you're asking for: start typing "fire" and the list just shows "Firefox".
Are you having issues with this behavior or is that you need something different? Can you give more details on the current behavior to see how can I help you, please?

Comment: @DanielGuzman I think OP is having trouble accessing the suggestion via javascript, check console, it's logging `undefined`

Comment: @GrafiCode yeah that's right, I'd like to access that list programmatically. To clarify, the javascript was an example of something I'd like to achieve

Comment: I've made the script and HTML into a snippet so that it's easier to see what's going on. You can do this yourself by following the FAQ [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)

Comment: Got it, @digitalWestie. I've provided an answer which should get a list suggestions based on the input, in JS, as you said. I lowercased them so the input can match better. Is there a problem with that? To keep the original case it can be improved a bit more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```js
// Obtain the available browsers
let options = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#browsers option')).map((option) => option.value);

document.getElementById('myBrowser').addEventListener('input', function () {
  const hint = this.value.toLowerCase();
  // Obtain options matching input
  const suggestions = options.filter((option) => option.toLowerCase().includes(hint));

  console.log(suggestions);
});
```

```html
<label for="myBrowser">Choose a browser from this list:</label>
<input list="browsers" id="myBrowser" name="myBrowser" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome"></option>
  <option value="Firefox"></option>
  <option value="Opera"></option>
  <option value="Safari"></option>
  <option value="Microsoft Edge"></option>
</datalist>
```

This obtains the exact same list as on Chrome, but that may not be the case on other browsers.

As for directly accessing the proposed list from the browser, I cannot say for sure if that is doable.

Comment: this is constantly logging an empty array `[]`

Comment: I mean, I guess this approach can work but it's not quite the same as _accessing_ what is suggested by the datalist.

Comment: @GrafiCode I had to edit the code since there was a mistake, now it's working. Of course the comparison can still be vastly improved, this is just an example.  DigitalWestie:  I do not know if the suggested list is available somewhere, but in the meantime you might have to resort to this

Comment: Are you sure all the suggestions in every browser just test for startsWith?

Comment: @RuanMendes They don't, comparing lowercase would go a long way already. But as I said the comparison can be improved, it's an example. I'll edit. Btw someone just took my snippet, edited it and made his own answer lol ?

Comment: @Adri you can see the other approach is different, even if it uses parts of your code.

Comment: @GrafiCode he only changed the comparison, IMO that doesn't really help OP much more..

Comment: @Adri and yet, the other answer is logging in console the correct suggestions; if I type `f` it logs `Firefox`, `microsoFt edge` and `saFari`. Your answer does not.

Comment: @Adri They improved your answer, it's allowed.

Comment: Alright so I improved it more, all for the better

Comment: @GrafiCode The other answer should work when typing `F` also 

Comment: And with our suggestions, the downvote became an upvote. I would still add a disclaimer that the algorithm for searching is not a standard and is subject to change but that this works with existing browsers (I'm not 100% sure about Explorer/Edge).

Comment: @Adri now it looks like a good answer. I can see your "opponent" resigned, you get the upvote :)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I totally encourage that code can't be owned, it's more about knowing the rules, no worries !

Comment: @Adri, I don't wanna compete. Sorry if you felt insulted or something. The logic was the same and I just wanted to avoid retyping everything. LOL. Even though it's allowed, in order to prevent competing or confusing digitalWestie instead of helping, and because I see you're willing to keep improving the solution more than me, I'll delete mine. xD I hope we can achieve a good solution for this question! ;)

Comment: @DanielGuzman No worries at all ! We all want to help :) Thanks

Comment: Yeah, @GrafiCode, I resigned because my intention was never a competition. I prefer to help this answer getting better (if I can) instead of fighting. xD Hope it was just a bad moment and no one feels this is a war. Haha.

Comment: Good stuff people. Perhaps one day there'll be a standard API for getting suggestions!

Comment: @DanielGuzman of course, I'm just kidding

Comment: Well, this could have escalated into the draft of such a standard API :) I've spent a bit more time researching and unfortunately I still can't say if such a thing exists as of now. But this should be more than enough for now if you don't have millions of options in your datalist ;) Good day

Answer (score 2):

One could implement such an additional `suggestedValue` property as getter of the `HTMLInputElement.prototype`.

The suggested solution has to be implemented as direct property of an input-element and not like the OP suggested ... *"`[inputElement].list.suggested`"* ... as property of a datalist-element ... since `<datalist/>`, via its `id`-attribute, can be referred to by more than just one element, each via its `list`-attribute.

Thus, a basic possible implementation (a bullet-proof version has to support multiple word matches from both, option-values and option-labels alike) and usage could look like follows ...

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('input[list]')
  .forEach(elmInput =>
    elmInput.addEventListener('input', ({ currentTarget }) =>
      console.log({
        currentTarget,
        suggestedValues: currentTarget.suggestedValues,
      })
    )
  );
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: calc(100% - 50px); }
```

```html
<div>
  <input placeholder="no browser" />
  <input list="" placeholder="broken browser" />
</div>
<div>
  <input list="browser-list" placeholder="my browser" />
  <input list="browser-list" placeholder="your browser" />
</div>

<datalist id="browser-list">
  <option value="Chrome"></option>
  <option value="Firefox"></option>
  <option value="Opera"></option>
  <option value="Safari"></option>
  <option value="Microsoft Edge"></option>
</datalist>

<script>
Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'suggestedValues', {
  get() {
    const search = this.value.trim().replace(/\s+/, ' ').toLowerCase();
    const { list } = this;

    return (list ?? null) && [
      ...list.options
    ]
    .map(({ value }) => value)
    .filter(value =>
      value.trim().replace(/\s+/, ' ').toLowerCase().includes(search)
    );
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
});
</script>
```